# Data size in Mongodb and PostgreSQL

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

Hi guys i have the same table with the sames indexes in `postgresql` and `mongodb`.I want to do a comparison on data size.
I am storing my data locally on my pc.I have the default configuration on both of them.I am using 4.4 version in mongodb and postgres12.I dont use any kind of compression.

The commands i execute for `mongodb` are

`db.mongodbbucketnocpu2index.totalIndexSize()` for index only

`db.mongodbbucketnocpu2index.dataSize()` for collection size without index

and in `psql` i use

`SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('oneindextwocolumns') )` for table size with index

`SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_indexes_size('oneindextwocolumns') )` size of indexes only

Are these commands equal?
It seems that the size is bigger in mongodb.Is there ant explanation for that?

Comment: "*I dont use any kind of compression.*" - yes you do. Postgres compresses values > 2K (including json and jsonb) automatically. You would actively need to disable this on a per column basis.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thats why PostgreSQL table is smaller than Mongodb table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didnt know that.Thanks! Can you confirm to my question please?